# Are spam invites on Google calendar dangerous?

Tags: spam, google-apps

I was recently "invited" to win a free phone on my Google calendar. At first I was concerned that my account was compromised, but i think anyone can send a calendar invite.

Is it safe for me to ignore these invites (and obviously never follow any links), or is there some action I need to take to secure my account?

Answer (score 1):

it is not dangerous unless you open a link, or open any kind of attachments. 
 of course vulnerability in Google calendar is another issue. (like zero-day exploits that are out of your hands).

in general enable two step security on your account, install update asap, and you are ok.